# Controller Script not Able to Get AJAX Data

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to pass serialized form data to a PHP controller with jQuery.  On successful processing, the user will be redirected to a results page.  I am not seeing any redirect taking place which tells me something is wrong with my controller.  I am seeing a sucessful AJAX callback.

The parameters are 'zipcode' and 'token'. The controller will validate the token, die if invalid, or perform the necessary logic once if valid.

I cannot find anything that stands out as incorrect about my code and could use an extra set of eyes.

HTML

```
<form action="" class="zipsearchform">
      <div class="form-group">
         <h2>Search by Zip Code</h2>
         <label for="zip-search-field">Enter a Zip Code</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip-search-field" name="zipcode">
         <br>
         <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php if (isset($token)) echo $token; ?>">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default zipsubmitbtn">Find Notaries</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('.zipsubmitbtn').on('click', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var params = $('form.zipsearchform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'parseByZip.php',
        data: {paramString: params},
        async: true,
        success: function(){
            alert(params);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP Controller

```
<?php
include_once 'resources/functions.php';
$zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
$token   = $_POST['token'];

if (validate_token($token) && isset($zipcode)) {
    $pattern = '/^\d{5}([\-]?\d{4})?$/';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $zipcode)) {
        $radius = 25;
        include_once 'resources/apizip.php';
        header("Location: notaries.php?lat=$latitude&lon=$longitude&distance=$radius");
    } else {
        echo "Zip code field cannot be empty and zip code must have the proper format of 00000 or 00000-0000";
    }
} else {
    echo 'Unable to handle your request right now.';
}
```

Comment: where your `event` is defined? `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Ajax doesn't automatically process redirect headers like a full page refresh does (bear in mind, the whole _point_ of ajax is to avoid postbacks, redirects and page refreshes). Your JS would have to read the header and then do the redirect itself using a `window.location` command. But honestly if you're just going to redirect the user the moment the call completes, then why not just use a normal postback and redirect flow? It really defeats the purpose of ajax IMO. The other refactor you could do is to keep the ajax but return the results in the ajax response and display them on the same page

Comment: @ADyson I was thinking the same thing.  From an optimization perspective, I'd like to leverage the user's browser as much as possible, but any positive impact is probably negligible here.  It's probably easier to just do a normal flow like you said.  Thanks for the comprehensive reply.

Comment: with ajax on php side you cant redirect , better to send your url back to client side and then redirect via js like  window.location.href = response.redirect;   ......... however in your case there is no need of ajax , as you want to redirect it server side , so directly post data to server , remove ajax and you good to go